# Error upgrading arangodb 3.0.3 from apt

Tags: ubuntu, arangodb, apt

I've installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 arangodb from ppa using https://www.arangodb.com/download/ubuntu/, everything works fine, now after recalling the usual apt-get update/upgrade, I had to upgrade arangodb to the 3.0.3 release, but in the last part of the upgrade, on configuring, I get this horrible message and everything stops working:

```
Unpacking arangodb3 (3.0.3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up arangodb3 (3.0.3) ...
Upgrading database files.
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] ERROR cannot locate file 'server/initialize.js': No such file or directory
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] ERROR unknown script 'server/initialize.js'
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] FATAL cannot load JavaScript file 'server/initialize.js'
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] ERROR cannot locate file 'server/initialize.js': No such file or directory
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] ERROR unknown script 'server/initialize.js'
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] FATAL cannot load JavaScript file 'server/initialize.js'
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] ERROR cannot locate file 'server/initialize.js': No such file or directory
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] ERROR unknown script 'server/initialize.js'
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] FATAL cannot load JavaScript file 'server/initialize.js'
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] ERROR cannot locate file 'server/initialize.js': No such file or directory
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] ERROR unknown script 'server/initialize.js'
2016-07-17T21:02:52Z [16356] FATAL cannot load JavaScript file 'server/initialize.js'
dpkg: error processing package arangodb3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 arangodb3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried to uninstall it using apt-get remove and then reinstal again but nothing help.. any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same thing on their slack group,they upload a new package that replaced the erroneous one.

Try remove any cached packages from 
/var/cache/apt/archives/ and the install again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was a packages version which wouldn't properly configure the source during build.

We fixed this, and replaced the package. Currently our .deb packages don't have a package version (only the ArangoDB version) which we could increase to automatically guide the upgrade - thus flushing `/var/cache/apt/archives` is neccessary in order to get the new ArangoDB version with the fixed binary:

```
rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/arango*
apt-get --reinstall install arangodb3
```

will re-download the package and install the fresh package.

Sorry for causing inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I re-installed version 3.0.2 to continue working.

Comment: sudo apt-get install arangodb3=3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; i checked https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/7705, raised issue here, where they claim the error is as a result of default configuration of SSE4.2 that clashes with lower CPU types, check the conversation thread:

**Solution ?:** i directly downloaded the .deb file , my specific version was
**arangodb3-3.3.0-1_amd64.deb**(you can play around with the version numbers because the current version is arangodb3-3.9.1-1 ) , then i run the command to install below:

```
sudo dpkg -i arangodb3-3.3.0-1_amd64.deb
```

and on executing the command **arangosh** on the terminal ,wallah!:

```
Please specify a password: 

                                       _     
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __   __ _  ___  ___| |__  
 / _` | '__/ _` | '_ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __| '_ \ 
| (_| | | | (_| | | | | (_| | (_) \__ \ | | |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_| |_|\__, |\___/|___/_| |_|
                       |___/                 

arangosh (ArangoDB 3.3.0 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, VPack 0.1.30, RocksDB 5.6.0, ICU 58.1, V8 5.7.492.77, OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017)
Copyright (c) ArangoDB GmbH

Pretty printing values.
Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' version: 3.3.0 [server], database: '_system', username: 'root'
```

Answer (score -3):

It is only correct *startup-directory* on *arangod.conf*

*startup-directory = share/arangodb3/js*

*startup-directory = **/usr/local/**share/arangodb3/js*